# When I download an IPython notebook as a PDF, which font does it use?

Tags: pdf-generation, jupyter-notebook

Pretty simple question:

I like the font of the markdown cells when I convert a notebook to pdf and I would like to know what it is. I don't know how to find out so if someone else does, or knows what it is, I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the CSS of the notebook I get:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

Thats what you want I guesss?
Example see: http://www.cssfontstack.com/helvetica

Comment: I think that's correct. It looks slightly different in font stack and in the notebook, but it's close enough. Thanks!